# Resizing images in div to fit its height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with 6 images inside of it.
The images are different sizes and proportions.
Is there a way to resize them in css to fit the div without specifying the size for each one of them seperately?

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 pt-30">
  <img src="img/exploded/6.png" id="img6" class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.5s"/>
  <br>
  <img src="img/exploded/5.png" id="img5" class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.3s"/>
  <br>
  <img src="img/exploded/4.png" id="img4" class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.1s"/>
  <br>
  <img src="img/exploded/3.png" id="img3" class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.9s"/>
  <br>
  <img src="img/exploded/2.png" id="img2" class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.7s"/>
  <br>
  <img src="img/exploded/1.png" id="img1" class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.5s"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `img { max-width:100%; max-height: 100%}`

Comment: If you can make some fiddle demo. It would be more helpful for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#your-img {
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 300px; 
max-height: 300px;}
```

You can use any value you like in % or px.
Just play arround with the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
img { width: 100% ; max-height: auto; }
```

Should give you what you want

Edit: swapped css elements

Comment: If I do this, then every image has the height set to 100%, so the div only contains the first image, the rest are sticking out of it...

Comment: Sorry, try it the other way round? Swap the width and height

Comment: If that doesn't work, what do you mean by "fit the div"?